# Created a type alias for big.Int - but I can't Set it using its pointer receiver?

Tags: go

I thought a type alias would be more elegant than embedding a struct.
You see, if I create a new type `BigInt` that embeds `big.Int`, I'd have to take care that the embedded big.Int is initialized at all times, and unless I reimplement big.Int's like Cmp, Add, Sub, all the code that depends on this new type needs to know that `BigInt`'s methods actually receive a `big.Int` for their arguments. Which is stupid.

So I tried aliasing a type.

```
type BigInt big.Int

// String casts BigInt into big.Int and uses its String method.
func (b *BigInt) String() string {
    bc := big.Int(*b)
    return bc.String()
}
```

But Setting the pointer receiver is now very tricky because I don't have access to the internals of big.Int. This following code doesn't work at all:

```
// UnmarshalJSON casts BigInt into big.Int and uses its UnmarshalJSON method.
func (b *BigInt) UnmarshalJSON(text []byte) error {
    bc := new(big.Int)
    err := bc.UnmarshalJSON(text)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    b = b.Set(bc)
    return nil
}

// Set is different from big.Int.Set() in that you must use the value it returns
func (b *BigInt) Set(i *big.Int) *BigInt {
    iB := BigInt(*i)
    b = &iB
    return b
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

That isn't a type alias, it's a new type, and therefor has *none* of the methods of the underlying `big.Int` type. A type alias would be `type BigInt = big.Int`, but then you couldn't define new methods on it. A type's methods are locked to its package: there is no way to define methods on an imported type *in addition to* the methods it already has defined. Embedding is the closest you're likely to get to that. More likely you want to reconsider your design, most likely by creating functions that take a `big.Int` instead of trying to define new methods.

Comment: Yes, I decided that I will mostly use big.Int and convert into this BigInt type only when strictly necessary, taking advantage of the fact that converting is very straightforward.

I think you answered my previous question on the same subject as well, thanks! After a few months living with an embedded struct solution (which you also recommended back then), I feel that this is simply more elegant.

Comment: Actually, I think back then you also recommended that I rethink my design. But it didn't sink in until today

Answer (score -1):

I forgot that I can dereference the pointer receiver /left hand side of the `=` sign as well. This does exactly what I wanted...

```
// Set makes a BigInt equal to a given big.Int.
func (b *BigInt) Set(i *big.Int) *BigInt {
    iB := BigInt(*i)
    *b = iB
    return b
}
```